# What is the difference between google's Dataflow and google's dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

DataFlow itself has ETL,computation and streaming process why do we need to go for google's Dataproc?

Answer (score 5):

[Google Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) is a fully managed and self-optimizing cloud service that lets you use the [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org) programming model to write your batch and streaming data processing pipelines. It's integrated with many open source and Google Cloud data sources and sinks.

[Google Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/) is a fully managed cloud service for running Apache Hadoop and Apache Spark clusters in a simple cost-effective way. If you have existing data processing pipelines that use Spark, Hive, or Pig this is an quick and easy way to move your pipelines. You can install custom packages, start/stop and scale these clusters at any time. On top Google Dataproc is integrated with many of Google Clouds data services.